# Late binding an Object in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, late-binding

I am getting the "run-time error 429" in my attempt at late binding to the VBProject object:

```
Dim vbProj As Object
Set vbProj = CreateObject("ActiveDocument.VBProject")
```

Is there something fundamental I am failing to understand?

For example, how would you write the code in [article 308340](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308340) to use late binding?:

```
 Sub CheckReference()

        Dim vbProj As VBProject  
        Set vbProj = ActiveDocument.VBProject

        For Each chkRef In vbProj.References

          If chkRef.IsBroken Then
             Debug.Print chkRef.Name
          End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: The link you posted doesn't go anywhere. Does the early binding version work for you? If not, then the problem's not in your code, it's in your system.

Answer (score 4):

Dennis,

if you are running this from within Word, then you don't need to use CreateObject().

Set vbProj = ActiveDocument.VBProject  will work.

if you are running this from elsewhere, then you may need to create Word object first and load the document:

```
  Dim a As Object
  Dim vbProj As Object

  Set a = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  a.Documents.Open "C:\temp\test1.docx"
  MsgBox a.Documents.Count
  Set vbProj = a.ActiveDocument.VBProject
```

In both cases you may get the "Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is not Trusted" which resolves through Macro security settings, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282830.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you come up with that progid (ActiveDocument.VBProject)? Generally progid's are of the form AppName.ObjectName, as in Excel.Sheet or Word.Document. IIRC, VB6 doesn't support OLE Automation itself; rather, it supports *creating* OLE Automation servers and clients.

**Update:**

Ok, I see what's going on now. ActiveDocument.VBProject isn't a valid progid. ActiveDocument is a property of the Word.Application object, which has a progid of (surprise!) "Word.Application".

So you want Meringros answer.

Comment: Instead of adding the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library" at design time, I need this to be done at runtime. 

I am going to add some significant edits to my question.