# Adding type library automatically in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro in Excel 2013 for automate some tasks for program named Simpack. This program has a COM-Interface support for scripting.

But there's a problem occurs when i'm close and open the excel, i should select the COM-Server from

VBA > Tools > References > SIMPACK.DIR > simpackcomslv.exe

and then macro works

Otherwise it gives an error in available references list like that:

> MISSING: simpackcomslv Type Library

Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: Is it actually registered?  I mean you say Tools->References and do you check a checkbox or do you navigate to file and select the file?  To register an exe requires  `<Full path of the EXE file> /RegServer`  https://www.razorleaf.com/2009/11/registering-dlls/

Answer (score 0):

You need a late binding of the variable, which uses the `simpackcomslv.exe` library.

Something like:

```
  Dim specificVariable As Object
  Set specificVariable = CreateObject("simpackcomslv-or try a few names here")
```

[Late binding an Object in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836237/late-binding-an-object-in-vba)

[MSDN Late Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation)

Comment: i have object like in my module but with your reply i understood should i put it to ThisWorkbook ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vitaya's answer.  If you need to go further then one can programmatic ally add references with this type library.

```
VBIDE  
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB
```

but questions have to be asked about why the reference has gone missing.  If you deploy a workbook from a machine that has the referenced software onto to one that doesn't then you are asking for trouble.

I suggest you review your deployment strategy.

Comment: i'm deploying the users who has this program on their machines. Also i have this program but as i said it's missing when i reboot my computer and then try to run macro from Excel.